# Creating a relationship between two tables and creating a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, relationships

Example, we have two tables as

```
creators (
creatorid int not null,
title varchar(100) not null, 
primary key(creatorid)
);

authors (
creatorid int not null,
titleid int not null,
primary key (creatorid, titleid)
);
```

Ok, I ask how to make relationship? I think that creatorid must relate with creatorid in second table, but I don't know how make it.

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE `authors` ADD INDEX ( `creatorid` );
ALTER TABLE `authors` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_creators` FOREIGN KEY (`creatorid`) REFERENCES `creators` (`creatorid`);
```

**More information:**

- [How MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)
- [InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: @KaliIlieva if my answer helped you, please, accept it to show other questioners the right solution.

Comment: One kind clarification. thinking about the FOREIGN KEY. Is it a must that the column in the child table to make foreign key is named like the colum we want to set the relation with, in the parent table? E.G. would it work if in the table authors we would have `creator_id_auth` as name instead than `creatorid`? I aks this because I'm in a similar situation and I can't get rid of creating the relation.

Comment: @Robert no matter how do you call your table columns unless you use natural joins (I'm 99% sure you don't).

Comment: Hello Hast! Thank you for your hint.. No matter what I try, I still get `#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`. Since I'm doing just tests and the rows are just a copuple for both the tables, is it because it is better to empty the tables or do I need some matches between the two columns (I mean the one in the parent and the FK in the child)? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Hello Hast, I tried delteting all the rows (they wre just 4, 2 for the parent table and 2 for the child) now the query worked. I'm wondering what it was the issue. Could it have been not matching values between the available rows in the child with the ones in the parent? Thank you for helping understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a constraint: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: A good answer should show how to do it, not just link to the documentation.

Comment: A good question should have demonstrated the most minimal search of documentation to accomplish the task.